# Why does it say that return value of method is never used?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, tic-tac-toe

Trying to make TicTacToe by myself. Making this method in order to check is Crosses win.
But it says that returned value never used.
sout of checkField[9] is like this
{0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8}
So it shall return true if you win and false if you don't.
But it doesn't.

```
     static boolean isCrossWin(String[] checkField) {

    if (
                    checkField[0] == "X" && checkField[4] == "X" && checkField[8] == "X" ||
                    checkField[3] == "X" && checkField[4] == "X" && checkField[5] == "X" ||
                    checkField[6] == "X" && checkField[4] == "X" && checkField[2] == "X" ||
                    checkField[7] == "X" && checkField[4] == "X" && checkField[1] == "X" ||
                    checkField[0] == "X" && checkField[3] == "X" && checkField[6] == "X" ||
                    checkField[6] == "X" && checkField[7] == "X" && checkField[8] == "X" ||
                    checkField[8] == "X" && checkField[5] == "X" && checkField[2] == "X" ||
                    checkField[0] == "X" && checkField[1] == "X" && checkField[2] == "X"
    ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `isCrossWin(fields);` method within your code? It should look like `Boolean result = isCrossWin(fields);` and actually do something with the result variable, whereas currently you probably have `isCrossWin(fields);` without using the return variable

Comment: Unless you get very lucky (e.g. using interned Strings) your comparisons to "X" will fail.  You need to use `equals` to compare objects.

Comment: Because you are ignoring it *at the calling site.*

Comment: Generally, don’t write code like `if(condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` Just write `return condition;`

Comment: @Holger, thank you for your reply. Can you please advice? If I use boolean method,that says: if (type Y) return true, else if (type N) return false, it underlines me in red? What if I need to choose between two options?

Comment: `if(condition1) return true; else if (condition2) return false;` is incomplete. It doesn’t say what should happen if neither condition is `true`. Depending on what should happen then, one of the conditions is obsolete. a) if `false` should be returned when both are `false`, the second condition is obsolete and you can just use `return condition1;` b) if `true` should be returned when both are `false`, the first condition is obsolete and you can just use `return !condition2;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to worry about with this code. The first, and more pertinent in my opinion, is dealing with the way you are checking the strings. In Java to compare two strings you MUST use `String#equals()` and not `==`.

To fix this you would have to go through and change every single
`checkField[x] == "X"` to `checkField[x].equals("X");`

This may not have been an issue up to this point for you (there are cases where == will still work, but they are accidents of the implementation), you must fix this.

Next, as far as not using the result goes, you need to look at how you are actually applying the method in the rest of your code. Some simple debugging tips you could use to see what is actually happening is either using a [debugger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) or by simply adding print statements in both of the return cases. Either way, if the function actually isn't returning something, that would definitely be your best guess for finding out why.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try my best to make code better and cleaner.